# Prove that $\sqrt{13}$ is irrational in 3 ways.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

I am asked how to prove that the $\sqrt{13}$ is irrational in 3 ways. I only know of one, where we assume $\sqrt{13} = \frac{a}{b}$ where $a, b$ are coprime, and we prove with contradiction that $13 \mid a$ and $13 \mid b$.

However, I am not sure where to begin with the other two proofs. I thought that this was the only way to prove irrationality of a number. I would really appreciate some help on where to start/look for to start the two other proofs.

Comment: One might explore the fact that $\sqrt{13}$ is, by definition, a root of $x^2-13$. The rational root theorem, for example, could provide one such proof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two other proof techniques you can use are :

- The rational root theorem : Let $f(x) = a_0 + a_1x + \cdots + a_nx^n$ be a polynomial, and let $\frac pq$ be a rational root of $f$. Then $p$ divides $a_0$ and $q$ divides $a_1$. For using this to prove that $\sqrt {13}$ is irrational, we create the contrapositive : if $f(x)$ is a polynomial as above, and for every $p$ dividing $a_0$ and $q$ dividing $a_n$ we have $f(\frac{p}{q}) \neq 0$, then every root of $f$ is irrational. Now, $x_0 = \sqrt{13}$ satisfies $f(x)= x^2-13$. You can see that $f$ has no rational roots using the rational root theorem, so $x_0$ must be irrational.
- Let $S = \{n \in \mathbb N : n\sqrt 13 \in \mathbb N\}$. If $\sqrt {13}$ is rational then $S$ is non-empty because $\sqrt{13} > 0$. Let $n \in S$ and let $q = n(\sqrt{13}-3)$. Then $q<n$, $q \in \mathbb N$ , and $q\sqrt{13} = 13n - 3n\sqrt{13} \in \mathbb N$ by $n \in S$. Therefore, $S$ has no minimal element despite being a subset of the natural numbers, a contradiction.

Comment: In the step where you go from $|13b^2-a^2|$ to 1 you implicitly use the fact that $13b^2-a^2$ cannot be zero.

Comment: @jMdA You may see the second method. Indeed, the first method actually says that $|13b^2-a^2| \neq 0$ using the number of times $13$ appears in the factorizations of $a$ and $b$, but that is circular , so I had to give this proof.

Answer (score 3):

It is realtively easy to prove that if $q\in\Bbb Q$ is such that $q^2\in \Bbb Z$, then $q\in\Bbb Z$ as well. Once you have established that, you only need to prove that there is no integer with square $13$, and there must be three, four or perhaps ninety-seven trite ways to prove it.

Comment: The very thing that the poster wants to know how to prove is something for which your argument is "It is relatively easy to prove.", without mentioning specifics of the proof.

Comment: @MichaelHardy It doesn't seem to me that OP is asking specifically for a proof, but rather for ideas of proofs. The lemma I'm mentioning is a divisibility consideration of essentially the same difficulty as the proof he already knows (if anything, I would contend whether or not it qualifies as a different proof, or just as a verbose workaround). It can be done in a couple of ways: the rational root test has been mentioned elsewhere, but a direct proof with fundamental theorem of arithmetics is within the realm of possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\sqrt{13} & = 3 + \text{a fractional part, since } 3^2<13<4^2 \\[8pt]
& = 3 + (\sqrt{13}-3) \\[8pt]
& = 3 + \frac{4}{\sqrt{13}+3} \text{ by rationalizing the numerator} \\[8pt]
& = 3 + \frac 1 {(\sqrt{13}+3)/4}
\end{align}
Since $3<\sqrt{13}<4,$ we have $1 < (\sqrt{13}+3)/4 < 2,$ so $(\sqrt{13}+3)/4$ is between $1$ and $2.$

So we have
\begin{align}
\sqrt{13} & = 3 + \frac 1 {1 + \left( \frac {\sqrt{13}-1} 4 \right)} \\[12pt]
& = 3 + \frac 1 {1 + \cfrac 3 {\sqrt{13} + 1}} \text{ by rationalizing the numerator as before}
\end{align}

Continuing in this way, we get
$$
\sqrt{13} = 3 + \cfrac 1 {1 + \cfrac 1 {1 + \cfrac 1 {1 + \cfrac 1 {1 + \cfrac 1{\sqrt{13}+3}}}}}.
$$
In the steps before this, the expression in the denominator was $\dfrac{\sqrt{13} + (\text{an integer})}{\text{an integer}}$ and the denominator in this last fraction was more than $1.$ But this time, the denominator is $1,$, i.e. we have $\dfrac{\sqrt{13}+3} 1.$ This means that now in place of $\sqrt{13}$ at the end of this long expression one can put this entire continued fraction, and we get

$$
\sqrt{13} = 3 + \cfrac 1 {1 + \cfrac 1 {1 + \cfrac 1 {1 + \cfrac 1 {1 + \cfrac 1{6 + \cfrac 1 {1 + \cfrac 1 {1 + \cfrac 1 {1 + \cfrac 1 {1 + \cfrac 1{\sqrt{13}+3}}}}}}}}}}.
$$

And then we can do that again. And again. We get this repeating sequence:

$$
3, \, \overbrace{1,1,1,1,\,6,}\, 1,1,1,1,\,6,\, 1,1,1,1,\,6,\, \ldots
$$

The part under the $\overbrace{\text{overbrace}}$ must keep repeating. This could not happen if this number were rational, as we will argue below. To see, why, suppose we start with a ration approximation to $\sqrt{13}$:

\begin{align}
\sqrt{13}\approx\frac{119}{33} & = 3 + \frac{20}{33} = 3 + \cfrac 1 {1 + \cfrac{13}{20}} \\[12pt]
& = 3 + \cfrac 1 {1 + \cfrac 1 {1 + \cfrac 7 {13}}} = 3 + \cfrac 1 {1 + \cfrac 1 {1 + \cfrac 1 {1 + \cfrac 6 7}}} \\[12pt]
& = 3 + \cfrac 1 {1 + \cfrac 1 {1 + \cfrac 7 {13}}} = 3 + \cfrac 1 {1 + \cfrac 1 {1 + \cfrac 1 {1 + \cfrac 1 {1 + \cfrac 1 6}}}}.
\end{align}

But **we cannot keep getting smaller positive integers forever.** So if we start with a rational number, this process cannot go on forever; it must end. But as shown above, if we start with $\sqrt{13},$ it does not end; it just keeps repeating.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $\sqrt{13} = \dfrac k \ell$ where $k,\ell$ are positive integers and the fraction is in lowest terms.

Then $$\frac{65\ell -18 k}{5k - 18\ell} = \sqrt{13}$$ but here the numerator and denominator are positive integers smaller than $k,\ell$ respectively.

Answer (score 0):

We can use a primitive Pythagorean triple (PPT).
By the Pythagorean theorem, there is a right triangle with hypotenuse
$\,\sqrt{13}\,$ and legs $\,2,3.\,$
Suppose that $\,\sqrt{13}=a/b\,$ for some $\,a,b\in\mathbb{Z}^+\,$
where $\,a,b\,$ are relatively prime. The given right triangle is similar
to one with hypotenuse $\,a\,$ and legs $\,2b,3b\,$ which is primitive
since the sides are relatively prime.
Use the known parametrization of PPTs to get relatively prime $\,m,n\,$ such that
$$a = m^2+n^2,\,\, 2b = 2mn,\,\, 3b = m^2-n^2.$$ The
last two equalities give $\,3mn=m^2-n^2,\,\,\,n(n+3m)=m^2,\,$ and
$\,n\,$ divides $\,m^2\,$ but
$\,m,n\,$ are relatively prime which implies a contradiction. Hence
$\,\sqrt{13}\,$ is irrational.